# Как нарисовать фигуру линии, как показано ниже, используя заданные значения оси с соответствующей меткой на оси x, оси y и заголовке

Tags: python

[image: График]

## Matplotlib - это библиотека 2D-графиков Python, которая создает высококачественные графики

## и цифры, что помогает нам визуализировать большие данные для лучшего понимания.

Comment: Ну нужно так нужно. Рисуйте…

Comment: Не умею рисовать, буду благодарен если вы попробуете

Comment: с чем именно у вас возникли проблемы с рисованием линии, с меткой, с чем то еще? Здесь принято задавать один технический вопрос и приводить свои попытки решения. ["Как задать хороший вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ["Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Со всем у меня возникли проблемы, я не могу вообще это сделать